# vCenter permission to perform this operation was denied (Converting windows server 2008 R2)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-vcenter

I am trying to convert a windows server 2008 R2 using vCenter. First, i would like to note i already successfully converted a windows server 2008 using the same process. The process fails for this specific server.

Im using the VMWare vCenter Converter Standalone v5.5.0 and i'm trying to convert a physical windows 2008 server to a virtual one.

After digging the internet i found several solutions:

Adding the user to the local administrators group on both the source and destination servers Running the software as an administrator (right click > run as an administrator)

I have tried both options, yet i still get "permission to perform this operation was denied". I am running vCenter from a windows 7 computer which is part of the domain and the account is part of the local administrators group. Same account is part of the windows server Domain Admins group and local Administrators group.

Any ideas on how i can bypass this error ? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: First off, what software are you using to run the conversion?  The vCenter Converter Standalone client or some third party application?

Comment: Im using the VMWare vCenter Converter Standalone v5.5.0

Comment: Is this a Physical to Virtual or other type of conversion?

Comment: Physical to virtual conversion.

Comment: When setting up the conversion are you able to view the details of the 'source' physical machine?  Also does it get past the point of installing the files and services on the source?  If so, tell it to not remove the files when completed and try changing those services to run as the domain administrator on that physical machine, restarting the services and attempting the conversion again.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the help. I'm unable to see the details of the server. i get the error at the first screen (power-on machine > IP + username / PWD ). Clicking on the view source details OR clicking continue returns permission error.

Comment: Have you tried shutting the physical server down completely and doing a cold boot?  Also have you tried other user accounts?

Comment: I have tried different accounts, yes. i haven't tried shutting down the source server

Comment: I'd recommend a cold boot on that server to see if something is hung up.  If that is not the case there may be other security software such as an anti-virus program or software firewall blocking it.  Also make sure the physical machine does not have any local security or group policies that block the ability to install programs by users.  A bad policy can block even admin users from installing applications.

Comment: We don't use any special policies and we didnt have any problems installing software on the server previously. The antivirus and firewall have already been disabled so it doesnt appear to be the reason. I will try the cold boot and update.

Comment: I'd still check the local security policies on the machine to make sure that Symantec or other software hasn't altered them.  Let me know how the cold boot goes.

Comment: No go on the cold boot unfortunately. We don't use symantec software (at all !! ) exactly for those reasons. I'm double checking the policies and altering software right now.

Comment: Disabled all antivirus / antispyware software & firewall. Still permission denied. The policy applied is the default policy without any changes, and i was easily able to start a software installation using the same user.

Comment: Well, next I'd try installing the vCenter Converter on the physical machine and convert directly from it to the vCenter environment. Make sure to right-click 'run as admin' of course.  If THAT doesn't work I'll have to regroup.  Never had one not run from the local machine before.

Comment: Alright. i tried it from the source server and im getting the same error. from the logs, im able to pull this error: [01264 error 'wizardController'] Must be administrator to access physical computer . i am a domain admin AND a local administrator. no idea what else i can try

Comment: Okay people. here is my solution. ignore the stupid bug and just go around it. Enable the server build-in Administrator account and use THAT one to bypass this bug.

Comment: Wow, glad you figured it out.  I would contact VMWare support on that to see if they are aware of it.  That's a pretty severe issue.

Comment: No problem, sorry it didn't help much.  Glad you figured it out though.  Add your solution as an answer so it can be recorded outside of comments.

Answer (score 4):

Check the logs in c:\users\all users\vmware\vmware converter standalone\logs\worker.xml (this might not be the exact string but should get you there).

I also tried both of the above fixes without success. My worker log showed that it was still not running the process as a full administrator (even with right click-> run as administrator). 
"UAC is enabled! blah blah blah" in the log

I got it to work by turning off UAC on the Win7 host and rebooting. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-user-account-control-on-off#1TC=windows-7

After reboot I still right-clicked -> run as administrator for vConverter but I was finally able to P2V without issue.

Ah, just saw the comments vs answer. Yes. Running as the local "Administrator" account would probably work as well since it treats UAC different for Administrator. I do not know the local "Administrator" account password and would not be authorized to change it… but temporarily disabling UAC does work.